# Published Umbraco site, now runs installer in loop

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, umbraco7

I just published my website I have been developing on local machine. And when I copied the files to the server, and now enter the address, it just starts the Umbraco installer.

It does it both front-end and back-end.

It is stuck, it seems unable to find the installer.

In my console it says the following:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
/install/api/GetSetup
```

Comment: is the database there ?

Comment: what do the log files say? located in `App_Data/Logs`

Answer (score 0):

it usually happens when there is no permission to write to file structure. So you need to edit file permission.

Right click on the folder > properties and follows >

[image]